# Can I debug SQL problems via SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I'm installing a program that often throws an exception due to either a wrong parameter in an INSERT statement or permission problems on the database. I do have full administrative rights on the SQL Server and it would be nice to log failed INSERTs etc. and the reason why they failed. The stack trace from the C# code shows only that a parameter is too long, but not which one of them and what the value was. Therefore it would be the easiest solution to solve SQL problems via SQL Server Studio Management rather than making code changes to a release of a product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of parameters can be viewed in SQL Server Profiler (Sql Server Management Studio: Tools -> SQL Server Profiler). It can be configured to save trace to db (if you can't reproduce an issue on test environment), and catch only certain calls (for example you can specify the name of your stored procedure).
Here is screen shot of profiler with stored procedures calls with all parameters:
[image]